# Is the equivalence between tangent and cotangent bundles canonical for algebraic topologists?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Choosing a metric tensor $g$ on $TM$ one gets a vector bundle isomorphism $g^\flat\colon TM\to T^*M$. Changing $g$ we get different maps $g^\flat$.

I would like to understand the statement and its consequences for algebraic topology:

> Every two metric choices are homotopic.

My interpretation would be that the metric tensor is a (positive-definite) section $g\colon M\to \mathrm{Sym}^2(T^*M)$ and every two of these are homotopic (through positive-definite sections) by
$$H_t(x) = t g_1(x) + (1-t)g_2(x)$$

Similarily if I treat $g^\flat$ as a section of the *bundle* $\mathrm{Hom}(TM, T^*M)$ which is an isomorphism on each fiber, the above homotopy yields a homotopy (through isomorphisms as well) between any $g_1^\flat$ and $g_2^\flat$.

This would mean that from the point of view of algebraic topology, the equivalence between $TM$ and $T^*M$ is "canonical" (induced isomorphisms on (co)homology and similar concepts do not depend on the metric chosen).

Have I got this right?

Comment: "Canonical" would mean there is a preferred choice of metric but there is not, what we say instead is that we have a "contractible choice" of metric. There always exists a metric (over paracompact spaces) and the space of all metrics is contractible, but it's still important to bear in mind that we've made a choice. This distinction is especially important when studying subspaces of metrics with particular properties which are not homotopy-invariant (e.g. positive scalar curvature metrics).

Comment: In some contexts like classifying spaces there is not a canonical model of $BG$ but there is a canonical homotopy type and since all the constructions we do starting with $BG$ are homotopical in nature that's "good enough" and we can pretend like there is "the" $BG$, but in geometry the constructions that arise from a metric aren't always homotopy invariant, like curvature for example. (Also some topologists might still be pedantic enough to demand you say "a $BG$" and only talk about the uniqueness of its homotopy type.)

Comment: (Sorry for all the comments, I think I forgot to address your actual question.) As for wether the isomorphism $TM\cong T^*M$ is considered "canonical" I would personally say no. As you said, it *depends* on a choice of metric, which I don't consider canonical. For me it's analogous to vector space bases: you can always choose a basis for a vector space $V^n$ (even though the choice isn't contractible) and this induces an isomorphism $V \cong \mathbb{R}^n$, but I would not say "$V$ is canonically isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$" because everything is relative to the basis.

Comment: @William Thanks for your comments. An isomorphism $f\colon TX\to T^*X$ will induce a map $f^*$ between cohomology and if $g$ is homotopic is to $f$, then $g^*=f^*$. 
Choosing _any_ isomorphism $f$ induced from some metric seem to generate the same $f^*$? 
I understand that for a differential geometer these identifications are totally different – but if someone is interested only in functors that factor through $\textbf{hTop}$, the choice does not matter, does it?

Comment: Which cohomology theory do you mean? I'm used to maps between cohomology being induced by maps between spaces $f\colon X \to Y$, rather than an isomorphism $TX \to T^*X$. But I think you are right, if you are *only* concerned about functors that factor through **hTop**, then choosing a different metric will give you the same functor, unless I'm overlooking something. In that case I would call the *functor* canonical rather than the choices you had to make to produce it (like how there is a canonical homotopy type for $BG$).

Comment: For example to compute the functor $dim\colon FinVect \to \mathbb{N}$ for an arbitrary vector space $V^n$ you in principle need to choose a basis, but  any choice of basis gives an isomorphism $V \cong \mathbb{R}^n$ so $dim$ factors through isomorphism classes and so is "canonical" (doesn't depend on any of the choices you had to make).

Comment: We have different invariants given by functors that factor by $\textbf{hTop}$ (as cohomology) and an isomorphism $TX\to T^*X$ would give an isomorphism between associated invariants. However for different maps $TX\to T^*X$ the induced isomorphisms may by different. My point is that if we choose the map  $TX\to T^*X$ to be induced by _any_ metric, then the induced isomorphism should stay the same. (It is explained brilliantly in the answer below). Thanks for your time and sorry if phrased the question not clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being continuously isomorphic is stronger than being homotopy equivalent. The metric, as you say, provides a continuous isomorphism. In this sense, homotopy invariants are 'canonically' the same.

Notice that this is not the same as saying that the map induced on a homotopy invariant by two continuous isomorphisms are the same, but if they differ by a choice of the metric then, as you write, they are indeed the same.

However, this is not the only isomorphism possible between the tangent and the cotangent bundle of the manifold. Suppose your manifold admits a non degenerate closed two form $\omega:M\to \Omega^{2}(M)$, i.e. it is symplectic. Then there is an isomorphism between the tangent and the cotangent bundle induced via $v\mapsto \omega(v,-).$

This is not even a section of the same bundle and as you can check, two choices of the symplectic form are homotopic. Thus they give the same isomorphism on homotopy invariants, but in general different from the one induced by the metric.

Edit: Let me also mention a fact, which escaped me when I originally wrote the answer, which might also be helpful.

In general vector bundles over a manifold (more generally CW complexes) have the homotopy type of the base space. There are many ways to see this, the quickest being that if $p: E\to M$ is a vector bundle with fibre $V$, then the fibration

$$V \to E\xrightarrow{p} M $$

has contractible fiber and so $p_*:\pi_{i}(E)\to \pi_i(M)$ is an isomorphism for all $i>0$ which then implies that $E\simeq M$ as both $E$ and $M$ have the homotopy type of a CW complex.

So the homotopy type of a vector bundle is not that interesting of a question. There are more interesting questions one can ask, such as classifying vector bundles up to isomorphisms which takes us to the realm of topological $K$-theory, which is an interesting topic in and of itself.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! Indeed, this question was mainly motivated by the "canonical" identification of $K^0(TX)\simeq K^0(T^*X)$ (in the context of studying pseudo-differential operators on a manifold).

Comment: Yes, indeed, $K^0(-)$ is a topological invariant